# How do I automatically adjust the size of a font according to the layout in which it is located?

Tags: python, pyqt5

How do I automatically adjust the size of a font according to the layout in which it is located?

I have a main window. I have a layout centered in the middle of the static dimension x y. In this layout I have a longer text and only a few words fall between the edges of the layout.

The only solution I know is to manually change the font size or layout to fit the text in the layout.

Is there a solution for automatic adjustment of the font size? I want the layout size to always remain the same and only the font size to be adjusted automatically

Comment: That doesn't seem a good idea. Using a fixed size for the layout and changing the font size might result in making the text unreadable. Can you show us how it appears right now and how you would like it?

Comment: then it would be a good idea to change the size of the layout according to the length of the text? and if so how? I have seen that the relative unit 'em' is available, but how can it be applied?

Comment: Generally speaking, a UI should be able to adapt its *layout* based on the contents, ensuring that all elements are visible and consistent, that's why changing the font size is not a good idea. Depending on the situation there are different solutions: wrapping the text, using a scrollable text, or truncate with elision.