# automatic adjustment of the layout according to the size of the text

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I have a layout that contains a long text.
How to automatically adjust the size of the layout according to the size of the text? The result I want to get is the one in the first picture.
[image][image]

Comment: By default, QLabel doesn't wrap lines, so the layout should resize itself already, if by "layout" you mean [a Qt layout manager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html). Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70008153/pyqt5-how-do-i-automatically-adjust-the-size-of-a-font-according-to-the-layout-i?